# springboot java mysql syntax error at parameter

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have this application, java spring boot and mysql db.
When i try to run the following query, i get this error. 
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'email ='rahul@gmail.com.com'' at line 1`

Does anyone know know why?

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT voucher_code FROM voucher INNER JOIN "
        + "offer ON offer.name = voucher.offer "
        + " email =:email", nativeQuery = true)
     List<Voucher> getVouchers(@Param("email") String email);
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an "AND" before `email =`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing something between the two conditions `offer.name = voucher.offer` and `email =:email`, probably a `WHERE`, perhaps an `AND/OR`. I guess you wanted this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT voucher_code FROM voucher INNER JOIN "
    + "offer ON offer.name = voucher.offer "
    + "WHERE email =:email", nativeQuery = true)
List<Voucher> getVouchers(@Param("email") String email);
```